# prevent users from changing any values on the Opportunity

Tags: trigger, validation

I have to accomplish this - The System should prevent users from changing any values on the Opportunity record except the Opportunity Stage when the Opportunity Stage is set to "Final Bid Submitted" for Opportunities with ‘Testing’ Record Type.

Can this be achieved with Validation rule or I need to write trigger for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IF( 
(NOT(ISNEW()) && RecordType.Name == 'Testing' && ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Final Bid Submitted')), 
IF(ISCHANGED(StageName), 
FALSE, 
TRUE 
), 
FALSE 
)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Too long; didn't read version:**

A validation rule can be used, but, for your intended use, cannot be guaranteed to work 100% of the time.

If you need 100% assurance that your rule won't be circumvented, it's better to write a trigger (or a workflow rule with a field update) to change the `recordType` of your `Opportunity` and assign it (the `recordType`, that is) a page layout where every field except `StageName` is set to `read only`.

**long version**

This can be accomplished using a validation rule...to some extent.

It appears to be less of an issue in your case, but for sake of example let's take the following simplified case:

> You want to create a validation rule on `Opportunity`, which for this example we'll say has only 3 fields, `StageName`, `Amount` and `Description`.
>
> You want to prevent changes to all fields, except `StageName`, when `StageName` is `Contract Sent` or `Closed Won`

A potential validation rule to enforce this could be

```
AND(
  NOT(ISCHANGED(StageName)),
  OR(
    ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Contract Sent`),
    ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Closed Won')
  )
)
```

The issue with this is that if `StageName` is currently `Contract Sent`, and you change it to `Closed Won`, **you can also change `Description` and `Amount`.**

Now, I have no experience in accounting, but changing the `Amount` of an `Opportunity` after a contract has been sent seems like a bad idea.

To fix this loophole, we need to modify our example validation rule

```
AND(
  NOT(ISCHANGED(StageName)),
  OR(
    ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Contract Sent`),
    ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Closed Won')
  ),
  OR(
    ISCHANGED(Description),
    ISCHANGED(Amount)
  )
)
```

That was a fairly simple modification, and captures changes attempting to be made to the other fields. It still allows changes to `Description` and `Amount` when the `stageName` isn't `Contract Sent` or `Closed Won`.

The issue with this, however, is that we needed to add, into the validation rule, every field we want to prevent changes to. In practice, `Opportunity` has more than 3 fields. You would also need to update the validation rule every time you added or removed a field from `Opportunity`

Validation rules do have a character limit (I don't remember if the limit is 3900 or 5000), but given enough fields, you will not be able to include all of them.

The conclusion here is that validation rules don't work too well when you try to enforce something of the form `If condition x is true, prevent changes to all fields except field y`.

If you choose to go this route, the basic validation rule you would end up with could look like this

```
AND(
  RecordType.Name == 'Testing',
  ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Final Bid Submitted')), 
  NOT(ISCHANGED(StageName))
)
```

It can be easily circumvented, and you'd be relying on users not knowing about how to defeat your validation, or being too lazy to do so (if there's one thing that I know about salespeople, or users in general, they hate making extra clicks).

A more robust solution would be to either have a trigger or a workflow rule (with a field update) to change the `recordType` when your Opp's `StageName` reaches `Final Bid Submitted`.

The advantage to changing the `recordType` is that you can assign a different page layout to it. In that different page layout, you can mark your fields (save for `StageName`) as read-only.

Using this method, it's impossible for your users (except system administrators) to directly change any field except for the field(s) you want them to change.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is the best answer, but maybe it can help you. Here is the pseudo code. You can replace field names with the correct field names in your Validation Rule later.

```
AND(
ISCHANGED(Opportunity.LastModifiedDate),
Opportunity.Stage='Final Bid Submitted',
Opportunity.RecordType='Testing')
```

Comment: Its not working unidha